# What is string[,] and how could I search string[,] in a search engine?

Tags: c#, .net

I saw `string[,]` in one of my client's c# project.

What does the code mean?
Also, I noticed that I couldn't search it by popular search engines such as Google, GitHub search, and even the StackOverflow.
How could I search a keyword which contains `string[,]`

```
public static Dictionary<string, string[,]> bigtabledic = new Dictionary<string, string[,]>();
```

Comment: [Multidimensional Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: It's a two-dimentional string array. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays

Comment: *"How could I search a keyword which contains string[,]"* - you have to search for question which ask exactly that question first ;) [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4685615/1997232) and [here](http://symbolhound.com/?q=c%23+%5B%2C%5D) are results.

Answer (score 4):

String [,] is a two dimenstional array consisting of string objects.

The code says the following: Create key value pairs of a string as a key and a two-dimensional string array as a value.

Comment: @Sinatr None, it's from memory.